# Create 3D buildings for sloped rooftops

Tags: 3d, 3d-analyst, 3d-model

How can I create 3D buildings for sloped rooftops?

I have good experience for creating 3D buildings with flat rooftops (I get z from nDSM from stereo pair). Is there a way for convert  flat roofs  to skill-ion roofs (as image below) auto  using CityEngine or other software?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a rule simiar to:

```
Lot -->
    extrude(*height*)
    comp(f) {
        side: Facade.
        top: Roof
Roof -->
    roofShed(*angle*)
```

This splits the box you have when you do a flat roofed surface into its sides resp. facades and separates out the roof which you want to handle differently. Then you apply the `roofShed` operation which creates the sloped roof.